# Public IP address issue in AWS and Chef

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, devops, knife

When I stop and start the EC2 instance it sets a new IP address. but my chef server not aware of its changed IP. I am doing bootstrap each time I connect to apply new IP but I am loosing the versioning. How can I fix this?

Comment: are you destroying your ec2 instance or you just restart it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Chef so there may be some Chef-specific solution here, or there may be Chef limitations that are triggered if a host changes its IP.

As you've seen, public IPv4 addresses are released when an EC2 instance is stopped (and a new IP address is assigned when the instance is restarted) but there are some options:

- use an Elastic IP (that public IP is retained over stop/start)
- use IPv6 (the public IP is retained over stop/start)
- use private IP (if you can connect over VPN or other)

Answer (score 0):

EC2 intentionally changes the public IP address over a reboot.

If you want this to stop, you need to assign an elastic IP address to the instance.  The elastic IP address will remain until you release it.

Elastic IP address are free as long as they are in use. Amazon charge for them if your instance is down.